# How to pass javascript variable into php function on an Ajax url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to insert the value of parent into the "getFaculties()" function when i call the function using Ajax.

```
    function ajaxfunction(parent)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Connection.php?getFaculties('+parent')',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#selFaculty").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use a proper way to pass data from ajax to php

```
function ajaxfunction(parent)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Connection.php',
            data: {method:'getFaculties', value:parent}
            success: function(data) {
                $("#selFaculty").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
url: 'Connection.php?faculties='+getFaculties(parent),
```

Since that is  query parameter, given a name to it.

Answer (score 0):

use like this `function Declaration was wrong`

```
function ajaxfunction(parent)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'Connection.php?getFaculties='+getFaculties(parent),
            success: function(data) {
                $("#selFaculty").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your function first and get return value in variable and then send your ajax request.

```
function ajaxfunction(parent)
{
    var data_in = getFaculties(parent);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'Connection.php?getFaculties='+data_in,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#selFaculty").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```